# Pics included to make my Q more clear.How to write correct command line arguments for installing SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, database-installation

I have been trying to write the right command line for installing SQL Sever 2008 R2 Express version 4 days and I have read all related posts on this website as well as other website. I also have read the "[How to: Install SQL Server 2008 R2 from the Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)" on MSDN. But none of them works for me.

Now here is my arguments.

```
/qs /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=True /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

**Problem :By using it, the SQL installer can show up until the Installation Process and closes without any errors popping up.**

Here are steps my current can go through:

1.[image]

2.[image]

3.[image]

4.[image]

So as you can see, the SQL Installation can go to the Installation Progress: Validating feature settings and then it closes.

I have used all my ideas to find out what's wrong in my command line.

**Please help me to write the right command line for SQL Server 2008 R2 installation.**

Thank you!!!

Comment: What does "none of them works" and "find out what's wrong" mean? You haven't said what your actual problem is: do you get errors (and what exactly are they?); are some command-line options ignored; does something not work as you expect? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Pondlife thank you for your reply. Actually I have pointed out my problem and request. Now I highlighted these 2 parts in my post, please have a look. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it right.

Here is the command line I use and it works.

```
 /qs /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLEngine,SSMS /INSTANCENAME="Your instance name here" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Administrators" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

You can also change other accounts, but the accounts you are going to use must have been created in your system and it is better an admin account and you do not need to specify the password.